# Advertisement view sorted by Nodequeue relationship

Tags: views

I have a Advertisement type of View listing Ads by taxonomy but I need to order them by Nodequeue and I don't see it available in the Relationships area.
Is there a hack for this anywhere?

thanks

Comment: What version of Drupal and what version of Views?

Comment: Drupal 6.20 and Views views 6.x-2.12

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.
You need to tell the view to have a relation from Advertisement to Node (Ad: Aid). Do this by going to Relationships and adding a relationship based upon "Ad: Aid". You'll then see under Fields all of the Node fields such as Title and Body available. Then add another relationship "(Node) Nodequeue: Queue".